# Add Form frields to View

Tags: 7, views, forms

I'd like to generate a view of Employee names, but I'd like to embed it inside a form as well as add checkboxes next to each Employee name. I tried to use `Rewrite the output of this field` but my `<input/>` tag is getting stripped out when being displayed.

How would you recommend I do this?

Comment: VBO can be help full.

Comment: Yes, this appears to be close, but I don't want a drop down with multiple actions possible, I just want the checkboxes and the submit button. I don't see any way in VBO to do that. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using Views Bulk Operations to generate the page content and then I added some javascript and css to hide certain things and to also add some extra fields, etc.

It was a total hack, but it got me through on a time crunch.

Comment: would you comment on how you added extra fields? I'm having a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would have benefitted from the Editable Fields module (http://drupal.org/project/editablefields).

You can add the checkbox as a boolean field to the employee, I suppose, and then in the view choose "Editable" as Formatter. Works for more sophisticated stuff as Text fields etc. as well.